# MySQL - unknown database

Tags: mysql

Recently updated to MySQL 5.7.24 and can no longer access the databases for a kodi installation using command 'use MyVideos93' or any other kodi database. 'use mysql' works fine. Any suggestions?

```
root@localhost [(none)]> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| MyMusic52          |
| MyMusic60          |
| MyVideos107        |
| MyVideos93         |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

root@localhost [(none)]> use MyVideos93
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'myvideos93'
root@localhost [(none)]> use mysql
Database changed
root@localhost [mysql]> show grants;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION        |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: is there anything in the mysql error log?

Comment: No... the error log shows no errors.

Answer (score 1):

@ted if you have the sql file for MyVideos93.

Thendrop current one and run these commands then.

`CREATE DATABASE MyVideos93;
 USE MyVideos93;`

then

`mysql -uroot –pmypassword < MyVideos93.sql`

Comment: I ended up just rebuilding the mysql server... Kodi generates all the tables and that is all I used it for, so thankfully this didn't have data I truly needed to recover.

Comment: so the problem is fixed, then you can mark it as answered.